# Make a Tuple from two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Suppose I have the dictionaries:

```
a={1:2,2:3}
```

and:

```
b={3:4,4:5}
```

I want to make a tuple such that:

```
t=({1:2,2:3},{3:4,4:5})
```

Comment: Just do `x = (a,b)`

Comment: `t = a, b` is probably the simplest, parentheses aren't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put them in a `tuple` literal:

```
t = (a, b) # or t = a, b
```

Now, `print(t)` returns `({1: 2, 2: 3}, {3: 4, 4: 5})`.